# Prove the additivity of Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am reading the proof of the additivity of Lebesgue measure from Stein & Shakarchi's *Real Analysis*:

[image]

I do not get why $\sum_{j=1}^N m(F_j)\geq\sum_{j=1}^N m(E_j)-\epsilon$. Is it because $m(F_j)\geq m(E_j)-\epsilon/2^j$ for all $j$? But then by what theorem/principle, since $m_*(E_j\setminus F_j)\geq \epsilon/2^j$ is an entirely different thing?

Comment: Hi! Since $F$ and $E-F$ are disjoint, it should hold $m(E)=m(E-F)+m(F)$. Does it? If so, your inequality follows, I think.

Comment: I don't think so. What you just said is exactly additivity for disjoint measurable sets of Lebesgue measure, i.e. what we want to prove. So far we only have additivity for sets with nonzero distance (but not necessarily disjoint)

Comment: It is $m_*(E_j-F_j) \leq \epsilon/2^j$ instead of $m$. I learnt the Lebesgue measure through the Riesz Representation approach, and don't know Stein's construction much. I suppose he has already proved the inner regularity of $m$. That is, for any measurable set $E$, $m(E) = \sup\{m(F): F \subset E, F\text{ is compact}\}$. Then the existence of such $F_j$ follows immediately.

Comment: @QiyuWen I am sure it is $m_*(E_j-F_j)\leq \epsilon/2^j$. By definition of measurability applied to $E_j^c$, given $\epsilon/2^j$, there exists open set $U_j$ containing $E_j^c$ such that $m_*(U_j-E_j^c)\leq\epsilon/2^j$. Take $F_j = U_j^c$, we get $m_*(E_j-F_j)\leq \epsilon/2^j$ since $E_j-F_j=U_j-E_j^c$

Comment: So I have no problem understanding the existence of $F_j$ as constructed by Stein

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the sub-additivity of exterior measure. Since $E_j=(E_j-F_j)\cup F_j $, $m_*(E_j)\leq m_*(E_j-F_j)+m_*(F_j)\leq \epsilon/2^j + m_*(F_j)$.